# How to use __index as a function?

Tags: function, lua, lua-table, metatable

I'm trying to imitate:

```
b = {1,2,3}
a = setmetatable({1,nil,3},{__index = b})
print(a[2]) -- prints 2
```

with that:

```
b = {1,2,3}
a = setmetatable({1,nil,3},{__index = function(t,k) rawget(b,k) end})
print(a[2]) -- nil
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can also spare an upvalue and change `rawget(b,k)` to `rawget(t,k)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a value in the metamethod:

```
return rawget(b,k)
```